# Starting an activity of a custom type from a native extension

Tags: android, flash, air, air-native-extension

I am using native extensions to build a custom video recording interface, the code to launch this activity is:

```
    @Override
public FREObject call(FREContext freContext, FREObject[] args) {

    Context context = freContext.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, VideoRecorder.class);

    int layoutID = freContext.getResourceId("layout.video_recorder");
    int surfaceViewID = freContext.getResourceId("id.surfaceView");
    int toggleRecordingButtonID = freContext.getResourceId("id.toggleRecordingButton");

    myIntent.putExtra("layoutID", layoutID);
    myIntent.putExtra("surfaceViewID", surfaceViewID);
    myIntent.putExtra("toggleRecordingButtonID", toggleRecordingButtonID);

    context.startActivity(myIntent);
    return null;
}
```

Since I'm using custom activity I've added the following lines to my Flash manifest xml file:

```
<application android:enabled="true">
<activity android:name="com.xxxxx.videorecorderlib.VideoRecorder"></activity>
</application>
```

"com.xxxxx.videorecorderlib" being my native Android package in which VideoRecorder resides.

When I build and run the app through Flash and on my Android phone I get the following error in the ADT LogCat:

> 07-22 17:25:33.282: D/VideoRecorder(15369):
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {air.com.xxxxx.videorecorderprototype/com.lxxxxx.videorecorderlib.VideoRecorder2};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Where "air.com.xxxxx.videorecorderprototype" is my Air app ID. Please can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error? I've tried adding the `<activity>` tags in the Android native manifest too but I still got the same errors (tried the fully qualified name and the . syntax).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, found the reason why it was not working. I had the `<application>` tag as child of `<manifestAdditions>` instead of `<manifest>`.

Hope this helps someone down the line!